# How to keep a cell value updated while the spreadsheet is in use

Tags: excel, vba

I just started on VBA and i am facing some problems while coding.

I am developing a solution to be used with RPA, and for this to work i need to a fixed cell in an spreadsheet to keep the cell location value retrieved by the function below:

```
Function FindCell()
Dim CellLocation As Range
Set CellLocation = Sheets("Data").Range("A:A").Find("OBRC", LookIn:=xlValues) 'Returns the cell in which OBRC is found
```

And to this function fulfill my needs, i implemented the second part of the code where my function write the value retrieved in the cell P3:

```
Function FindCell()
Dim CellLocation As Range
Set CellLocation = Sheets("Data").Range("A:A").Find("OBRC", LookIn:=xlValues) 'Returns the cell in which OBRC is found


While ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("P3").Value = FindCell.Value


End With
Wend


End Function
```

But everytime i try to call this function i got the error

> Run-Time error 424: Object required

Comment: Side note: please remove the `While...Wend`...  you really don't want a loop, especially not an infinite one.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You want to find the cell where `OBRC` is stored in column A of the `Data` sheet? And then you want to write that value in `P3` of the data sheet? ... even thought that value will just be `OBRC`? Or do you actually want *the address* of that cell? Once I understand more clearly your requirement, I can probably help create more efficient code. The code above is ripe with issues, but I don't want to correct until I understand the exact requirements.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I am trying to get the cell location eg(A1, A5, A16), and write it down in the cell

Comment: @BigBen i need a repetitive structure to this value keep being updated, so are you saying that i need to built it where the function is called ?

Comment: You've built an infinite loop... that's not the repetition you want.

Comment: @LucasSilva - you want to loop all the sheets in the workbook? or what do you want to repeat? Or do you want to capture everytime `OBRC` is entered in a different place?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman to get the reference cell, my function search for the last cell that has the value `OBRC` and them get the value.

Comment: @LucasSilva - see my answer below.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman i will try it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
Recur to an event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     'whatever code you're trying to implement
End sub
```

Try the image example, that will for sure give you an idea ;)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman yes it does, as by embedding OPs desired action in a worksheet_change event will keep it running "while the spreadsheet is in use".

Perhaps you would like to explain why it wouldn't achieve OPs desired action?

Answer (score 0):

First, a function is meant to return a value. For the code above a procedure will work very simply.

Note the use of `SearchDirection` in the find function to find the last occurence of the value.

```
 Sub FindCell()

    With Sheets("Data")

       Dim lastRow As Long
       lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

       Dim foundIt As Range
       Set foundIt = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find("OBRC", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

       If Not foundIt Is Nothing Then
           .Range("P3").Value = foundIt.Address
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, everytime i try to run it i got the error : 'Compile Error: Expected: end of statement'

Comment: @LucasSilva sorry. try now. I left something from my previous idea. should be fixed